# Chart.js doughnut chart with gradient along path/stroke

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

**I'm trying to achieve this using chart.js:**

[image: mockup of doughnut chart with gradient]

Notice how the gradient follows the stroke, starting at the red colour at  0° and ending in the yellow colour, with a smooth gradient between.

I've tried a few methods found while searching around but have had to admit  defeat (at least I've hit the limit of my canvas and js skills)...

Using the usual chart.js setup and customising using:

```
Chart.pluginService
```

for the centrally placed number, this is what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/voodoo6/c2tzydv3/19/

The closest I can find to a solution to creating the gradient was here:
[Angle gradient in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223950/angle-gradient-in-canvas/22231473#22231473)

There is an issue related to this on the chart.js repo [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/111)

I'm struggling to get it working – has anybody achieved this using chart.js or have any idea how it can be done?

Thanks as usual!