# Angle gradient SVG using paper.js

Tags: javascript, svg, gradient, paperjs

I'm using paper.js to create gradient forms.
From the examples below i have found the way to do the Linear Gradient and the Radial Gradient, but i have not found any example or orientation to do Angle Gradient with paper.js and SVG, is this even possible?

[image]

Here are the 2 examples i have found in the oficial [paper.js site](http://paperjs.org/download/)  to create Lnear and Radial Gradient  and the code to achieve this forms.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gradients</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <!-- IE 9: display inline SVG -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/paper-full.js"></script>
    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
        var stops = [new Color(1, 1, 0, 0), 'red', 'black'];

        var radius = view.bounds.width * 0.4,
            from = new Point(view.center.x),
            to = from + [radius, 0];

        var circle = new Path.Circle({
            center: from,
            radius: radius,
            fillColor: {
                stops: stops,
                radial: true,
                origin: from,
                destination: to
            },
            strokeColor: 'black'
        });

        var from = view.bounds.leftCenter,
            to = view.bounds.bottomRight;

        var rect = new Path.Rectangle({
            from: from,
            to: to,
            fillColor: {
                stops: stops,
                radial: false,
                origin: from,
                destination: to
            },
            strokeColor: 'black'
        });

        //rect.rotate(45).scale(0.7);

        document.body.appendChild(project.exportSVG());
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

no unfortunately, this is not supported by Paper.js.
And there are low chances that it supports it soon, unless the Canvas API itself (which Paper.js uses to draw) supports it.
Maybe you can find a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223950/angle-gradient-in-canvas).